# Python Tesseract "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, tesseract, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make an OCR program in python, and I'm using pillow to make an image high contrast black and white, but when I try to use tesseract to extract the text, I get the following error output in terminal:

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "OCR.py", line 41, in <module>
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
  File                 "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 122, in image_to_string
config=config)
  File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 46, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess    .py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess    .py", line 1333, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:     '/usr/local/bin/tesseract'
```

### Python

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

sens = int(input("Sensitivity (0-255): "))

im = Image.open("book.jpg")
pixels = np.asarray(im)
width, height = im.size

px = pixels.mean(axis=2)
ppx = px.flatten()


for i in range(ppx.size):
    if ppx[i] > sens:
        ppx[i] = 255
    else:
        ppx[i] = 0


pixels = ppx.reshape(height, width)

img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(pixels))
img.show()
img.save("images2.jpg")

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [README](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/README.rst#installation), you must install [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) to use pytesseract.

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install tesseract-ocr
```

Comment: Also don't forget to set `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '<full_path_to_your_tesseract_executable>'`